# Typescript error 2345 seems to be inconsistent across simple examples

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question about the basics of Typescript.

Consider this example:

```js
// Interface 1
interface Empty {}

// Interface 2
interface Single {
    a: number;
}

function printEmpty(arg: Empty): void {
    console.log(`Hello World.`);
}

function printSingle(arg: Single): void {
    console.log(`Hello World, a: ${arg.a} `)
}

const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};

// ===================== Tests =====================

// TEST 1
printEmpty({a: 1, b: 2});  // valid

// TEST 2
// Q1: if the above is valid, why is this invalid
printSingle({a: 1, b: 2}) // invalid!

// TEST 3
// Q2: if the above is invalid, why is this valid
printSingle(obj);  // valid
```

The error I get is

> Argument of type `'{ a: number; b: number; }'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'Single'`.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and `'b'` does not exist in type `'Single'`.(2345)

Why does TEST 2 fail but TEST 1 and TEST 3 pass?

Here's a reproduction of this error on the official TS playground: [[LINK]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&q=469#code/PTAEEkDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUBGAsAKAJYwIrqgCiAtgA7QCeoA3gL554gRFJoYBMehcLqQDKhAOYAbDAzyg5oZAC5QkAK4UARggDceFrjyJVkVNHwB7SKCrwBlGrQAUyeGOX26ASmUA3c-gATRll5VEsAZ3MpADoJczFHAAMACVgJONAAdXN4CQDoxM9dXH1DY1MLKxsBUUhJWGdXZVr671A-QODceVAwyEiYuISUtIzs3ICAGgVlABIGFzFo5CZQQr1WXD7w6FBzDQArUABeRiUsaY1lHiZitjBjx6fnl9fQABVYHfCT17%20-zbsd5kYTvLB4aowDxOBbKTCXa5MIpydg%20ZASQKAsDA0GgPi4dgARUwynwiFA0AAFhhkBpzD4MPgfmiMVNQAB3Sn0JkUyk8wgszG4SHQFpSRywi6gK54pGgdgC9GBACEWI%20ILBAGZ7qBCTxSeSqTS6QzQPzIIK2ZzuT8qTzLRDbDAxQ19gdkfKwA7cEA)

Comment: [Why are all types assignable to empty interfaces?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) and [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755

Comment: When you provide an object literal to a function that expects a certain type, TypeScript will assume any additional properties were accidents, and warn you about them. After all, why would you be adding extra properties that the function can't use? However, if the object is already in a variable, then it may have been used in other locations where the extra properties were needed. It seems to simply be a tradeoff TypeScript has chosen, where TypeScript is trying to let you know when it thinks you've made a mistake, at the cost of some consistency.

Comment: @ScottyJamison That makes sense (thanks!) but why is there no error in TEST 1, which also passes additional properties? I guess the `Empty` interface is a special case?

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the links! Very helpful! Especially the second one since it's now been deprecated.

Comment: @user1814274 unfortunately the TS handbook has been updated to a new one and not all of the old topics were covered in the new one. This is the only version of the handbook that actually explains what excess property checks are and how/when they work. The new handbook covers some topics that weren't there before and does have better explanations but the old one is still handy for some references.

Comment: There's still [the release notes introducing the excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) but it would be nice if it had a place in the handbook proper.